# pass an array from php file to js file

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I want to pass an array from a PHPfile to a JS file. How is it possible?

**php file**

```
    for($i=2015,$k=0;$i<=$year;$i++,$k++){
      for($j=1,$m=0;$m<12;$j++,$m++){
       $query="select * from tracker where (year='$i' AND mounth='$j')";
       $result=mysqli_query($dbCnn,$query);
        $count[$m]=mysqli_num_rows($result);
     }
      $yM[$k]=$count;
    }
   mysqli_close($dbCnn);
```

I want to use `$yM` array data in my JS file. I'm using this data for my Highcharts.

Comment: http://php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX for call your php script. In your php script, do a echo with json_encode and parse with js.

Example, with jQuery :

Your php file :

```
    for($i=2015,$k=0;$i<=$year;$i++,$k++){
      for($j=1,$m=0;$m<12;$j++,$m++){
       $query="select * from tracker where (year='$i' AND mounth='$j')";
       $result=mysqli_query($dbCnn,$query);
        $count[$m]=mysqli_num_rows($result);
     }
      $yM[$k]=$count;
    }
   mysqli_close($dbCnn);

   echo json_encode($yM); // make a json string.
```

Your javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = 'yourPHPfile.php';

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        async : false,
        success : function(response){
            $json = $.parseJSON(response);
        }
    });
</script>
```